# How can i check if a list is exsisting in a redis database using node-redis?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I am trying to create a custom list according to the route accessed from the root route. I am using express routing parameters to get the name of the list and add some predefined values to the list.

But i want to check first if the specified name (list name) hasn't already been used by another list in the Redis database. I am using the **client.exists** command to check if the specified key(list name) exists but it doesn't seem to work at all. Here is **my code:**

```
app.get("/:customListName", (req, res) => {
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;
  console.log(customListName);

  client.exists(customListName, (err, reply) => {
    if (reply === 0) {
      console.log("Doesn't exist!");

      const multi = client.multi();
      const customList = ["Have fun!", "Play Games!", "Watch Movies!"];
      customList.forEach((item) => {
        multi.rPush(customListName, item);
      });
      multi.exec();
    } else {
      console.log("Exists!");
    }
  });
});
```

From the code i have logged the accessed route and a message that specifies if a list exists or else but am surprised to see that the route is shown (which is 'home' in this case) but no message is logged as you can see below:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node Redis 4.x uses Promises instead of callbacks. My guess is you are using that version and that this is the source of your problem. Try this:

```js
app.get("/:customListName", async (req, res) => {
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;
  const itExists = await client.exists(customListName);
  if (itExists) {
    /* do one thing */
  } else {
    /* do something else */
  }
});
```

Not 100% sure but I think the `.exists` command returns a boolean. But regardless, it'll certainly be truthy or falsy and so this code will work either way.

Comment: For the record, the `.exists` command returns a number. 1 if it exists and 0 if it doesn't.